# button onclick event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

in my react web app, i have a search button to fetch data from API.

if i put below code,its working

```
<div className="col m1 s1 ">             
<i className="material-icons" onClick={ ()=>this.handleJobSearchChange() } >search </i>
</div
```

but my requirement is to put the search icon as a button ,so i changed this code as shown below.

```
<div className="col m1 s1 ">          
<button className="btn btn-active grey waves-effect waves-teel"><i className="material-icons" onClick={ ()=>this.handleJobSearchChange() } >search </i></button>
</div
```

ie when i use button tag ,its not working. why?

this same code is working for another component in my code.
i already import materialised library in both components.
please let me know what is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: @Herohtar i already given onclick event associated with it

Comment: You have `onClick` set on the `<i>` tag that is inside the `<button>`. That won't work; it has to go in the `<button>` tag itself.

Comment: @problem is when i add button tag in that component. the same second code is worked in another component

Comment: i changed the click event  associated with button ,but not working for me

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in codesandbox . So we can check that and give you solution

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS this issue fixed simply by adding e.preventDefault() function to button onclick handler function. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed .

when i add e.preventDefault(); statement to onclick function;

```
 handleJobSearchChange= (e)=>
      {
       e.preventDefault(); 
.......some code
}
```

Thanks to all for the responses you were given

Answer (score 0):

Try using the event on the button other than the material icon. Creating event on material icon is not a problem though. If this does not work, try to inspect the button and check if there is element that is on top of your button preventing the icon to listen to the click.

```
<div className="col m1 s1 ">          
<button className="btn btn-active grey waves-effect waves-teel"onClick={ ()=>this.handleJobSearchChange() }>
<i className="material-icons" >search </i>
</button>
</div
```

Comment: when i click on it ,back to home page ,so not able to inspect what happening there

Comment: have tried to inspect the element and make sure there is no element on top of the button?

Comment: this part put in separate div, then how that can happened?

Comment: issue solved by adding e.preventDefault() on onclick handler function

Answer (score -1):

The onClick handler should be associated with the button className. For instance, the first button class "btn" goes like:

```
btn.onClick {
 ()=>this.handleJobSearchChange()
}
```